# Function Binding Issues on Callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I'm working with WebSocket and having an issue with a function showing incorrect data, All my code used to work with a Class-based component, I'm only trying to convert a class component that actually calls the connect method of Websocket to a functional-based component. The Websocket is class-based for instance.

So I have a WebSocket which on socket New Message sets callbacks.

```
  socketNewMessage(data) {
    console.log(data);
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    const command = parsedData.command;

    if (command === "userChatGroups") {
      this.callback[command](parsedData.chatGRoups);
    }
    if (command === "new_userChatGroups") {
      this.callback[command](parsedData.chatGRoup);
    }
  }
```

and here are the callbacks defined -

```
addCallbacks(userChatGroups, newUserChatGroup) {
   this.callback["userChatGroups"] = userChatGroups;
   this.callback["new_userChatGroups"] = newUserChat;
}
```

and then websocket finally return -

```
const WebSocketInstance = Websocketservice.getInstance();

export default WebSocketInstance;
```

Now the class-based component which I'm trying to convert to functional based -

let's call this component Chats-

this calls the connect method and a Websocket instance is returned.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedInUserDetail) {
      WebSocketInstance.connect(loggedInUserDetail[0].id);
    }
  }, [loggedInUserDetail]);
```

I have a helper function which checks the status of websocket -

```
  function waitForSocketConnection(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (WebSocketInstance.state() === 1) {
          console.log("connection is secure");
          callback();
          return;
      } else {
        console.log("waiting for connection");
        waitForSocketConnection(callback);
      }
    }, 10);
  }
```

and I check the status and map my callbacks - here is the problem-

```
  useEffect(() => {
    waitForSocketConnection(() => {
      WebSocketInstance.addCallbacks(
        setChatGroups,
        addNewChatGroup
      );
    });
  }, [loggedInUserDetail]);
```

I have a state to manage CHatGroups -

```
  const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);
```

the setChatGroups (which initially loads all the groups the users are associated with works fine and sets the state of chatsGroups) as -

```
  const setChatGroups = useCallback((userChatGroups) => {
    setGroups(userChatGroups); //whatever data it recieved from the websocket.
  }, []);
```

but the function addNewChatGroup always shows groups value as an empty array [] (it was updated earlier with setChatGroups). If I manually check the value of groups it is an array of n length, but in addNewChatGroup function, it always shows an empty array with the initial value [].

```
  const addNewChatGroup = useCallback(
    (newCHatGroup) => {
      console.log(groups);  **error -> this is always empty array** 
      // here I have to update. add the received value with the previous
    },
    [groups] // callbacks used hoping this will bind
  );
```

- 

In the class-based component I used to set callbacks on the constructor and used to bind with this, but I'm not able to do it here, can anyone help what I'm missing?

I'm sure it is a binding issue. maybe.  May I know the reason for this binding failure?

Comment: Try to change `function waitForSocketConnection(callback)` by an arrow function: ```const waitForSocketConnection = (callback) => { /* ... */ }```

Comment: @JStw same result

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understood correctly your problem, it could be link to multiple things.

The problem actually is I don't have a clear view on all your components, maybe you can try to paste a sandbox link or something like that with a "simple structure".

I tried to reproduced a typescript version, I don't know if it could help:

```js
class MyWebSocket {
    private static _instance: MyWebSocket;
    public callbacks: any = {};
    public connected: boolean = false;

    public socketNewMessage(data: any): void {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('new message received:', parsedData);

        const command = parsedData.command;

        if (command === "new_userChatGroups") {
            this.callbacks[command](parsedData.newGroupAdded);
        }
    }

    public addCallbacks(elements: {command: string, func: Function}[]) {
        console.log('adding callbacks...', elements);

        elements.forEach(element => {
            this.callbacks[element.command] = element.func;
        });
    }

    public connect(): void {
        setTimeout(() => this.connected = true, 1100);
    }

    public static getInstance(): MyWebSocket {
        return this._instance || (this._instance = new MyWebSocket());
    }
}

class SocketUtils {
    static waitForSocketConnection(callback: any): void {
        const waitingInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (MyWebSocket.getInstance().connected) {
                console.log('socket is connected! processing callback...');
                clearInterval(waitingInterval);
                callback();
                return;
            } else {
                console.log('socket is not connected after 1sec, waiting...');
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}

class Chat {
    groups: string[] = ['group of JStw'];

    new_userChatGroups(group: string) {
        this.groups.push(group);
    }
}

class Main {
    constructor() {
        const myChat = new Chat();
        MyWebSocket.getInstance().connect();

        // waiting connections.
        SocketUtils.waitForSocketConnection(() => {
            console.log('waitForSocketConnection is triggered, adding callbacks...');
            // adding callbacks
            MyWebSocket.getInstance().addCallbacks([{command: 'new_userChatGroups', func: myChat.new_userChatGroups.bind(myChat)}]);
        });

        // Waiting 5min to dispatch an message
        setTimeout(() => {
            // testing eventing after getting connection
            MyWebSocket.getInstance().socketNewMessage(JSON.stringify({command: 'new_userChatGroups', newGroupAdded: 'group of Ranu Vijay'}));
        }, 5000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('program finished, results of chat groups:', myChat.groups);
        }, 10000);
    }
}

new Main();
```

**Output:**
[image]

I'm more specialized on functional component by using react so without a link to investigate all your code, it will be complex to help.

I don't know if you are using a library, but there is this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-websocket which seems to be really ultra simple to use without managing socket connection/disconnection.

For me if I had to implement it, I would say:

- Component ChatGroup which is using websocket hook `const { sendMessage, lastMessage, readyState } = useWebSocket(socketUrl);` and contains the state `groups, setGroups`.
- Component Chat which can use the `sendMessage` from props of ChatGroup component and call it from this component if a join a group.

Then your "parent" component is managing the state and is controlling the data.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/socketexample-f99x7n?file=/src/websocket.js not a practical running demo, but this is my code structure, you can check addNewChatGroup in app.js always have a group state of  []